# how to refrence Linq2SQL class from a static class

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am having a strange problem, i have a static class like this

```
  public static class BlogDataAccess
{
    private static Blog _Blg;
    public static Blog Blg
    {
        get
        {
           _Blg = new Blog ();
           return _Blog ;
        }
    }

}
```

then in my page i do the following

```
  var DataContext= new DataClasses();
  BlogDataAccess.Blg.ArticleTitle ="Title";
  DataContext.Blog.InsertOnSubmit(BlogDataAccess.Blg);
  DataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

the record get inserted but with null value of the ArticleTitle field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each time you're accessing `BlogDataAccess.Blg`, you're creating a new object. I think you mean to implement the lazy-instantiation like this instead:

```
public static class BlogDataAccess
{
    private static Blog _Blg;
    public static Blog Blg
    {
        get
        {
            if(_Blg == null)
                _Blg = new Blog();

            return _Blg;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: wow, just wow man you have saved me hours, it worked like charm thanks a lot really :) 
is there any down side of this technique ?

Comment: Well, it assumes you'll need one and only one instance of the object available. The only down-side of lazy instantiation is if the object's construction takes a long time. You might see some lag the first time it is accessed.

Comment: so as you saw it is a blog module and maybe 3 users are working on adding, editing article, so will this make a problem ?

Comment: No, no, should be fine. Unless of course your Blog() constructor tries to read the whole thing from the database into memory or something.

Comment: no man, it is as i told you , i will give user control panel to manage blog entries, and then will use the db to show the articles in the front end.

thanks again really :)